# DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

Datagrid control is missing in Toolbox. I tried to add it from WPF components, but it is not listing there also. And iam using 3.5 framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a Datagrid, I have used a ListView which contained a GridView. Here is the [tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1) I started from. (Haven't worked very much with Datagrid, so I don't know if there are any big differences)

A simplified version of what I'm workign with is:

```
<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="lstItems" 
         PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="lstActions_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
           PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="lstActions_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
              <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
          </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.View>
         <GridView x:Name="gridView">
             <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DisplayName}" />
             <GridViewColumn Width="240" Header="Description"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
         </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</Listview>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can grab it from the [WPF Tookit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/).